# Getting image resolution in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, resolution

I am working on a project where I need to find image resolution for an image or any relation between image height and width with the resolution of image.

When we right click on an image and select `properties->details`, we have the resolution information.

How can we extract that information in `matlab`?

Is that information does not depend on image properties because somewhere I read image has only pixel information, `ppi` or `dpi` depends on printer, sensors.

Comment: On the off chance it's GeoTIFF's and a "spatial/ground resolution" you're after then look at [geotiffinfo](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/map/ref/geotiffinfo.html)

Comment: I am working with "jpeg" image. for "tiff" image, we can get resolution using imfinfo.. IS there any other way to extract information provided in image properties->details, can be seen using right click on the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `imfinfo` matlab function, which returns a structure whose fields contain information about the image.

For example:

```
info = imfinfo(YOUR_IMAGE);
w = info.Width;  %An integer indicating the width of the image in pixels
h = info.Height; %An integer indicating the height of the image in pixels
```

In your case, you probably want to get: `Horizontal resolution` and `Vertical resolution`. So use:

```
xR = info.XResolution
yR = info.YResolution
```

For more information: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html

Comment: I need resolution of the image, and imfinfo does not contain resolution of the image for "jpeg" image. But, right click-> properties->details has the information about xresolution and y-resolution.. i nedd those resolution information.

Comment: If, width and height is somehow related to xresolution and yresolution, then it will be helpful. But, i do not have any idea, nor i am getting. Need help in this.

Comment: You can open the picture with `.jpg` extension instead of `.jpeg`, Width and Height will give you the resolution like you see in the details. Note that `.jpg` is the same as `.jpeg` (the dos extension is `.jpg` while other o.s might use `.jpeg`)

Comment: This is what my doubt is, HOW WIDTH and HEIGHT ARE RELATED TO RESOLUTION of an image.
Need Help in this

Comment: We're talking about `pixel resolution`, the numbers in the variables `Width` and `Height` are the number of pixels in `y` and `x` dimensions. So, the resolution is `w` x `h`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_resolution

Comment: And the other one is Embedded Resolution.Is there any way of finding that. The paper i am referring for my project talks about the embedded resolution only, which is there in properties. 
And thanks for clearing confusion between these 2 types of resoltions

Answer (score 1):

For a JPEG (or TIFF) image you can extract all the EXIF information and tags using the function [exifread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/exifread.html). This should contain the all the information contained in the image properties.

Example:

```
exif = exifread('Image.JPG')
```

Comment: From the documentation of the function: `Note:   exifread will be removed in a future release. Use imfinfo instead.`

Comment: exifread is working for .tiff not for .jpg, i have matlab version 7.12.0.635 and imfinfo does not contain the information that can be seen using right click->properties->details. I guess, metadata information for .jpg can only be seen using properties, there is no way exist, because, these information are not stored for jpg in metadata, but how one can see it in properties??

Comment: Metadata should be able to be read by both `exifread` and `imfinfo`. If these functions are not returning the required information try something such as [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) which is command line so can be called by matlab. If you are struggling further share the image (e.g. via dropbox) and I can look into it

Comment: ExifTool is giving the information but, it shows resolution unit "none" for .jpg image and Resolutions 1 which does not match with the information given in properties of image.
For the images, where resolution is shown by "imfinfo", like ".tiff" image, it is showing correctly. I am sharing with you the link for both the images
[link] (https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B6lmg-YOCFOEdVVNS1N2SnVRdkU)

Answer (score 0):

For the ".jpg" images, based on the device from which it has been taken, the resolution information will be present, so for every jpeg images, there may not be resolution information present in metadata, and whatever information is there, can be seen using "imfinfo" or "imageinfo" in matlab.
For changing resolution there are commands present in matlab, which can be easily found